# How to retrieve a volume parameter and making it display in result.jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller

I am really confused about this question. I have tried everything and nothing works.

I want to be able to get the volume and display it as param.volume. However it will return zero if I do it as a scriptlet.

I want to be able to create the getter method named getVolume that returns the volume of the cube when called (side * side * side).

My getter method is:

```
package servlets;



public class Cube {



    private int side;


    private int volume;

    public void setVolume(int volume){
        this.volume=volume;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        volume=side*side*side;
        return volume;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

}
```

In the CalcServlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class CalcServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/calc")
public class CalcServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


                String scube=request.getParameter("cube");

                Cube obj=new Cube();


                try{
            int cube=Integer.parseInt(scube);
            obj.setSide(cube);
            obj.getVolume();



            request.setAttribute("cube", obj);



            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            }
                ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
            //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp"); 
                RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher ("/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }

    }
```

In result.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  

<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myjsp" %>
<%@ page import="servlets.Cube, servlets.CalcServlet " %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<body>

<h2>Cube Info Using JSP 2.0 </h2><br>
<b>Side of a Cube: ${param.side} </b><br>
<b>Volume of a Cube: ${param.side*param.side*param.side}</b><br>

 <br></br><br>
 Using Custom Tag:
<myjsp:displayform color="red"></myjsp:displayform>


 <br></br><br>
<h2>Using JSTL:</h2>
<h2>Cube Info Using JSP 2.0 </h2><br>
<b>Side of a Cube: ${param.side} </b><br>
<b>Volume of a Cube: </b>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.side*param.side*param.side>10}">
    <li><span style="color: red;">Volume: ${param.side*param.side*param.side}</span></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <li><span style="color: black;">Volume: ${param.side*param.side*param.side}</span></li>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>



</body>
</html>
```

The result displays because param.side is being read. However I want to do this with param.volume. Please help!! I have tried everything.

Comment: Couple of things:

 - The result of  obj.getVolume(); is not inserted into any variable.
 - You set the request attribute when responding, why?
 - In your JSP code you're not using volume.

Comment: Hi Shay,
OK I tried what you're saying. I am not using param.volume because it wont even display. I tried int volume=obj.getVolume(); and it still didnt work. Then I referenced param.volume in my JSP Code. It didnt solve the issue. What do you mean I set the request attribute when responding??? I thought it was to be only one request attribute

Comment: What I meant is where is your response:
Request in -> Response out

Comment: i did request.set attribute, but dont have a response object in the servlet because it sends it to the jsp page. none of the logic is done in the servlet. can you give an example of how to do response out?

Answer (score 1):

first fix your getter/setter for volume. right now your getter act like a setter.

```
public void setVolume(int Volume){
        this.volume=volume;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
```

then in your serlvet (proper pratice would be to do that in an utility class)

```
            int side=Integer.parseInt(scube);
            obj.setSide(side);
            int volume= side*side*side; 
            obj.setVolume(volume);

            request.setAttribute("cube", obj);
```

you named your parameter which contains the bean Cube "cube". On that line
request.setAttribute("cube", obj);

so to access the bean cube in your JSP you should do like that

```
${cube.side}
${cube.volume}
```

or the proper way

```
<c:out value="${cube.side}"/>
<c:out value="${cube.volume}"/>
```

Comment: i did this in result.jsp:

<h2>Cube Info Using JSP 2.0 </h2><br>
<b>Side of a Cube: ${cube.side} </b><br>
<b>Volume of a Cube: ${cube.volume}</b><br>

Comment: I did exactly as you said for both the servlet and the jsp page and constructor. it still didnt work

Comment: it seems that the cube.volume wont be recognized, however when i do something like param.side, the side parameter displays because it was from the textbox. However. volume is returning zero if you use a scriptlet. i tried param.volume, but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to know the answer, I got it from a friend. Hope this will benefit the community.

In result.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  

<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myjsp" %>
<%@ page import="servlets.Cube"%>
<%
    Cube cube = (Cube) request.getAttribute("cube");
    int side = 0, volume = 0;

    if (cube != null) {
        side = cube.getSide();
        volume = cube.getvolume();
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<body>

<h2>Cube Info Using JSP 2.0 </h2><br>
<b>Side of a Cube: ${cube.side} </b><br>
<b>Volume of a Cube: ${cube.getvolume()}</b><br>

 <br></br><br>
 Using Custom Tag:
<myjsp:displayform color="red"></myjsp:displayform>


 <br></br><br>
<h2>Using JSTL:</h2>
<h2>Cube Info Using JSP 2.0 </h2><br>
<b>Side of a Cube: ${cube.side} </b><br>
<b>Volume of a Cube: <c:if test="${cube.volume}">10><font color="red"></font>the volume is ${cube.getvolume()}</c:if></b><br>

</body>
</html>
```

And in calcservlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CalcServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/calc")
public class CalcServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp"); 
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String scube=request.getParameter("side");

            Cube obj=new Cube();

            try{
            int cube=Integer.parseInt(scube);
            obj.setSide(cube);
                                     System.out.println("works");

            obj.getvolume();

            request.setAttribute("cube", obj);

            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            }
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp"); 
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }

    }
```

In Cube:

```
package servlets;



public class Cube {



    private int side;


    public int getvolume() {
        return side*side*side;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

}

In form.jsp:

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
</head>
<body>

            <h2>Side Form</h2> <!-- page heading -->

            <form method=post action="calc"><!-- open a neew form -->

            Side of a Cube: <input type=number name=side required><br> <!-- the iname parameter -->
            <br></br>
            <input type=submit value=Calculate><br> <!-- submit to the home page if everything is fine, else additem servlet and display the new item -->
            <br><br><br></br>
            </form> <!-- close form -->

</body>
</html>
```